# how to install Moloch with helm for kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, charts, docker-compose, kubernetes-helm

How can i install moloch via helm (or another) to kubernetes system?

steps here:

```
1. $git clone https://github.com/sealingtech/EDCOP-MOLOCH
2. $cd EDCOP-MOLOCH
3. $helm install moloch moloch/ --values moloch/values.yaml
4. $helm list (ok)
5. $kubectl get po (pending status)
```

result:

```
$kubectl describe pod moloch-moloch-capture-0
    
Warning  FailedScheduling  7m58s  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: ****1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity.****
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zfhR.png)

Comment: Are you using specific tutorial ? On which environment you are working on (AKS, EKS, minikube etc) ? Can you paste output of following commmands: $  kubectl get nodes  $  kubectl describe nodes

Comment: outputs are here:     master@ubuntu:~/Documents/EDCOP-MOLOCH$ kubectl get nodes
NAME           STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
minikube       Ready    control-plane,master   16h   v1.20.2
minikube-m02   Ready    <none>                 16h   v1.20.2

Comment: and also i added output of "kubectl describe nodes" on bottom:

Comment: Please paste output not as separate answer but add it to original post, do the same with information you have paste in comment section. I saw you have already found solution I've upvoted it to be more visible.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, so above helm scripts are true. After that you can get another error as i said in this content:([Error: secret "passive-interface" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65998472/error-secret-passive-interface-not-found/66008205#66008205))
so you can go step by step bros...

So, this problem about that used only one node, when you use two node or make configuration in yaml files. you can go up!

Answer (score 0):

```
$kubectl get nodes
```

[image]

```
$kubectl describe nodes
```

[image]