# Error: secret "passive-interface" not found

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, packet-capture

when i install moloch with helm to my kubernetes system (2 nodes that named minikube and minikube-02), i get this errori why, how can we resolve it?

Warning  Failed     7s (x6 over 49s)  kubelet            Error: secret "passive-interface" not found

note: I see that "passive-interface" on this file "https://github.com/sealingtech/EDCOP-MOLOCH/blob/master/moloch/templates/moloch-viewer.yaml"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem for this step, So you can use it for moloch:

```
$kubectl create secret generic passive-interface --from-literal='interface=neverforget'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I checked the helm template files and it appears the this secret isn't being created automatically so you should create it first before running this helm chart.

Comment: thanks 0xMH, so how can i create it, can you share with me or any documentation about it?

Answer (score 0):

$kubectl describe nodes

[image]

$kubectl get nodes

[image]